# AmazonSES not sending mail in some servers

Tags: php, web-services, codeigniter, amazon-s3

In my website i used  AmazonSES for sending mail. but it works fine in abc.com and not works in xyz.com, After sending mail mail in xyz.com return true. I used same code and credentials in both server. In xyz.com send php mails successfully.   I am used codeignator.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick suggestion, check the SES time by making an HTTP request to SES (e.g. wget -S "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"), and compare to your server's time. Update the server's time (or use NTP if you aren't already) and see if the problem resolves itself.